# What is the name of the poem Belle reads out?

Tags: plot-explanation, beauty-and-the-beast-2017

In one of the scenes from *Beauty and the Beast* (2017), they are both walking around the castle grounds outside in daylight as she reads a poem aloud about winter/snow/ice. I can't really remember any of the words, although the final word she read was glass and 'grass' featured as an earlier word. Timing wise it was before she left to return to the village, and I'm pretty sure before the ballroom dance.

What is the name, and what are the words, of that poem? Was it created specifically for the film? How does this poem contribute the overall value of the movie?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The poem is called "A Crystal Forest", written by William Sharp. The text of the poem is as follows:

> The air is blue and keen and cold,
>
> With snow the roads and fields are white
>
> But here the forest's clothed with light
>
> And in a shining sheath enrolled.
>
> Each branch, each twig, each blade of grass,
>
> Seems clad miraculously with glass:
>
> Above the ice-bound streamlet bends
>
> Each frozen fern with crystal ends."