# Poem that Belle reads in Beauty and the Beast

Tags: beauty-and-the-beast-2017

After Belle reads the [William Sharp poem "A Crystal Forest"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/70347/49) in the 2017 *Beauty and the Beast*, she goes on to read a second poem with something along the lines of

> For in that solemn silence is heard the whisper of every sleeping thing. Look, look at me, come wake me up for still here I'll be

or something like this at the end.

Was that also an existing poem or was that made specifically for the movie? In the former case, what poem was that and why was it chosen for this scene?